# I want to know the meaning of compile-time decisions

Tags: java, inheritance

What does it mean to say "with inheritance you're locked into compile-time decisions about code behavior".

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this post from [Donal Fellows on Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/224972/why-is-inheritance-only-defined-at-compile-time),

> Some languages are pretty strongly static, and only allow the
>   specification of the inheritance relationship between two classes at
>   the time of definition of those classes. For C++, definition time is
>   practically the same as compilation time. (It's slightly different in
>   Java and C#, but not very much.) Other languages allow much more
>   dynamic reconfiguration of the relationship of classes (and class-like
>   objects in Javascript) to each other; some go as far as allowing the
>   class of an existing object to be modified, or the superclass of a
>   class to be changed. (This can cause total logical chaos, but can also
>   model real world nasties quite well.)
>
> But it is important to contrast this to composition, where the
>   relationship between one object and another is not defined by their
>   class relationship (i.e., their type) but rather by the references
>   that each has in relation to the other. General composition is a very
>   powerful and ubiquitous method of arranging objects: when one object
>   needs to know something about another, it has a reference to that
>   other object and invokes methods upon it as necessary. As soon as you
>   start looking for this super-fundamental pattern, you'll find it
>   absolutely everywhere; the only way to avoid it is to put everything
>   in one object, which would be massively dumb! (There's also stricter
>   UML composition/aggregation, but that's not what the GoF book is
>   talking about there.)
>
> One of the things about the composition relationship is that
>   particular objects do not need to be hard-bound to each other. The
>   pattern of concrete objects is very flexible, even in very static
>   languages like C++. (There is an upside to having things very static:
>   it is possible to analyse the code more closely and — at least
>   potentially — issue better code with less overhead.) To recap,
>   Javascript, as with many other dynamic languages, can pretend it
>   doesn't use compilation at all; just pretence, of course, but the
>   fundamental language model doesn't require transformation to a fixed
>   intermediate format (e.g., a “binary executable on disk”). That
>   compilation which is done is done at runtime, and can be easily redone
>   if things vary too much. (The fascinating thing is that such a good
>   job of compilation can be done, even starting from a very dynamic
>   basis…)
>
> Some GoF patterns only really make sense in the context of a language
>   where things are fairly static. That's OK; it just means that not all
>   forces affecting the pattern are necessarily listed. One of the key
>   points about studying patterns is that it helps us be aware of these
>   important differences and caveats. (Other patterns are more universal.
>   Keep your eyes open for those.)

[image: profile for 74U n3U7r1no at Stack Overflow, Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers]